# Rows default order in UNION ALL mysql clause?.. Which row would be fetched first, I mean?

Tags: mysql, sql, union

If I, for example, have a real simple query:

> SELECT 1
>   UNION ALL
>   SELECT 2

and then fetch rows via Perl or PHP - would I have "1" as a FIRST row, and "2" as a SECOND? Is this behaviour described anywhere?..

Thanx

Comment: Yes you will have that output..

Comment: If you need a specific order, specify an `ORDER BY`. The SQL standard guarantees no order without one. In the case of your made up, not even close to the real thing example, it would return the result you want, but in any real working query it might not.

Comment: Union All is a fast query because it doesn't have an order at all, it just put everything together and display.... if you make union all + order by your DBA will kill you because that process should be slower...

Comment: Unless you specify an order by clause the optimizer is free to return the rows in any order, which may be different today than tomorrow or next year. (Comment to other comments: the union operator performs a distinct, which implies a sort. However, there is no guarantee that the order by will be the same as your expected collating order. Some RDBMS will perform a hash-based sort/distinct which may produce a surprising order.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no default order, not in tables and not in queries, unless you specify an explicit order with ORDER BY.

You would probably have 1 as first row, and 2 as second, but it's not default behaviour and it's not described anywhere. It's just coincidence!