# mysql query on two tables without getting duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with name, email. One from orders, one from newsletter signups.

All entries in order table have both name and email, but some newsletter signups have no name or a short form.

If I do a union with email, name I get email duplicates on the entries with name mismatch.

```
SELECT email, name FROM orders
UNION
SELECT email, name FROM signups
```

Example

```
andrew@xxx.com  Andrew
billy@zzz.com Billy
billy@zzz.com B
```

How can I retrieve email and name without email duplicates?

**NOTE**

All three given answers work, but *wolfgangwalter's* was fastest on sample data

```
2243    clients
11402   signups
1057 overlap (clients in signups)
```

**Returned**

```
12588 posts  320 ms - wolfgangwalter
12588 posts  360 ms - Jaugar Chang
12588 posts  23.5 sec! - McAdam331
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just group by `email`. This should leave you with distinct `email`s. For every `email` the first `name` is taken from the group. Since we sorted the union first, we will always get the `name` from `orders`.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM (SELECT email, name, 1 AS SortKey FROM orders
            UNION ALL
            SELECT email, name, 2 AS SortKey FROM signups
           ) AS list
      ORDER BY SortKey
     ) AS ordered_list
GROUP BY email
```

Here are some more ressources that might help to understand this query:

- [Rows default order in UNION ALL mysql clause?.. Which row would be fetched first, I mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708742/rows-default-order-in-union-all-mysql-clause-which-row-would-be-fetched-first)
- [MYSQL UNION ORDERING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267687/mysql-union-ordering)
- http://renormalize.org/post/24114561260/mysql-curious-features-non-deterministic-group-by

Comment: All three answers work, but this was fastest on sample data. See note at question

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```
SELECT 
    email,
    MAX(name),  --Get the max name from two tables 
    MAX(case source when 'o' then name else null end), --Get the max name from orders table only
    GROUP_CONCAT(name)  --will get "Billy, B" for billy@zzz.com
FROM
(
SELECT email, name, 'o' as source FROM orders
UNION
SELECT email, name, 's' as source FROM signups
) AS TMP
GROUP BY email
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can group by email. The problem is, only 1 row will be returned for email, so you need to decide which name to use to be returned with that one row.

You stated in your question that those in signups might not have names, or a short form, so I would assume you want to grab the name from the orders table. So what I would do is select the email and name from orders, and union it with email and names from the signups table, where the email does not exist in the orders table (that allows you to get what's left over). It would look like this:

```
(SELECT email, name FROM orders)
UNION
(SELECT email, name FROM signups WHERE email NOT IN (SELECT email FROM orders));
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/503f4/1) for it.

**EDIT**

This assumes email is unique, which I would expect it to be.